# Faced main.js:1 Uncaught TypeError: (intermediate value).getUser is not a function at HTMLInputElement.<anonymous>

Tags: javascript

I was learning how to use Webpack and when I try to execute code on key up event

I got the following error:

> main.js:1 Uncaught TypeError: (intermediate value).getUser is not a function
>       at HTMLInputElement.`<anonymous>`

As you can see two modules below, index.js serves as a starting file for bundling:

**HTML code**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">
</head>
<body>
   <div class="container-fluid">
       <header class="header">
           <div class="header--title-box"><h3 class="header--title  ">GitHub Finder</h3></div>

            <div class="header--inputBox">
<h1>Search GitHub Users</h1>
<p>Enter username</p>

<input type="text" class="header--input" placeholder="GitHub Username...">
            </div>
       </header>
       <main>
           <div class="container">
           <div class="profile"></div>
        </div>
       </main>

       <footer>Copyright 2018</footer>
   </div>

   <script src="./dist/main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**Index.js**

```
import {GitHub} from "./gitHub";
let input = document.querySelector('.header--input');

input.addEventListener('keyup', function(e){
    let inputValue = this.value;

    if(inputValue!==''){
        GitHub.getUser(inputValue)
        .then(data=>{
            if(data.data.message==="Not Found"){
                alert("Nothing found")
            }else{
                UI.showProfile(data.data);
                UI.showRepos(data.reposJson)
            }
        })

    }else{
        UI.clearProfile();
    }
})
```

**GitHub module**

```
export class GitHub{
    constructor(){
        this.clientID='6ea9567c0f22d48fb20e';
        this.clientSecret='a4ec6e6b2040ddd5d197079014f8a4e0fb7fe839';
        this.repos_count=5;
        this.repos_sort='created: asc';
    }

    async getUser(user){
        let response = await fetch(`https://api.github.com/users/${user}?clientID=${this.clientID}&clientSecret=${this.clientSecret}`);
        let repoResponse = await fetch(`https://api.github.com/users/${user}/repos?per_page=${this.repos_count}&sort=${this.repos_sort}?clientID=${this.clientID}&clientSecret=${this.clientSecret}`);

        let parsedJson = await response.json();
        let reposJson = await repoResponse.json();

        return {
            data:parsedJson,
            reposJson
        }
    }        
}
```

Comment: I assume these clientId and clientSecret are fictitious. If not, please remove them...and not just from this post. Consider using local environment variables to reference them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has nothing to do with WebPack.

`getUser` is a class method.

It appears to instances of `GitHub` not the `GitHub` constructor function.

```
const github = new GitHub();
github.getUser(inputValue)
```

---

Since github objects don't appear to store any data internally, it isn't clear why you are using a class in the first place. You would probably be better off with a plain object instead.

```
export const github = {
    clientID: '6ea9567c0f22d48fb20e',
    clientSecret: 'a4ec6e6b2040ddd5d197079014f8a4e0fb7fe839',
    repos_count: 5,
    repos_sort: 'created: asc',
    async getUser(user) {
        let response = await fetch(`https://api.github.com/users/${user}?clientID=${this.clientID}&clientSecret=${this.clientSecret}`);
        let repoResponse = await fetch(`https://api.github.com/users/${user}/repos?per_page=${this.repos_count}&sort=${this.repos_sort}?clientID=${this.clientID}&clientSecret=${this.clientSecret}`);
        let parsedJson = await response.json();
        let reposJson = await repoResponse.json();
        return {
            data: parsedJson,
            reposJson
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you for your kind comments, you mean instead of import I have to use const github = new GitHub();
github.getUser(inputValue)

Comment: No. You still need to import `GitHub` before you can use it.

Comment: thank you it worked finally, Quentin, I know it will seem quite weird but I have to ask this question:), I am beginner in programming and JS and I really admire such programming gurus as you are. The question I want to ask is what I need to do to become such a pro like you are.